# Is xlrd supported in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have seen posts in Google Groups and here that mention using xlrd in Google App Engine:

[How do you read excel files with xlrd on Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458388/how-do-you-read-excel-files-with-xlrd-on-appengine)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-appengine-python/xlrd/google-appengine-python/lMix6vXhvtA/O_ExzkGhsKEJ

but when I try to add it to the app.yaml file, it says "the library xlrd is not supported". Also, in the list of 3rd party libraries I don't see xlrd.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

But then other people seem to be using it on GAE, so does GAE support it or not? In the past I was able to import numpy successfully. Here is app.yaml. On main.py I have "import xlrd". Thank you very much.

```
application: uploadsample
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1" 
- name: xlrd
  version: "0.7.3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include any pure python third-party libraries with your app that you want. You don't specify them in app.yaml, that's only for third-party libraries that are included by Google on the servers.

xlrd is not "supported" per se, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you Wooble. When I remove those lines from app.yaml, it says: ImportError: No module named xlrd. But when I run Python IDLE by itself I can import xlrd, no problem. Do you know how I can troubleshoot that? Thanks again.

Comment: You need to include a copy of the module in your application directory when you deploy it.

Comment: Woobie is correct here. We don't supply `xldr`. You'll have to upload it along with your app.