# library xlrd is not supported

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xlrd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is xlrd supported in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140613/is-xlrd-supported-in-google-app-engine)

I am developeing a google app engine application ,
in which i want to read some exel file.
I am using xlrd lib but it showing me the error
***ImportError: No module named xlrd***

I have also added

```
libraries:
- name: xlrd
  version: latest
```

to the app.yaml file but it is showing error ***the library "xlrd" is not supported***

I have checked [Third-party Libraries in Python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)
But it seems thats google app engine doent support xlrd.

Is google app engine does support xlrd or not ? is there is another option ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140613/is-xlrd-supported-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE supports natively most of the default Python libraries and few Customized Libraries as mentioned in [Python Runtime Environment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime)

I have used xlwt and in the same analogy, I am assuming xlrd would also be supported (unless xlrd has any C extensions) which I am not aware of.

In order to use xlrd, you have to package it with your Python Source and Upload it to GAE. You cannot expect GAE to supply the library for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what about i want to run it locally on localhost?

Comment: @Nishant: It shouldn't be an issue. Just place xlrd in the src folder, and import it accordingly. When you upload it, just upload the entire src folder.